# How to translate text which contains url link using gettext and haml?

Tags: ruby, haml, gettext, padrino

I would like to know if it is possible to use fast_gettext the translate a short paragraph which contains a url link. I'm using a combination of **padrino**, **haml** and **fast_gettext**.

For example:

Please visit our [home](http://example.com/home) page.

Inside the **.haml** file, the code looks like this:

```
%p
  = _('Please visit our %{home_url} page') % {:home_url => link_to(_("home"), '/home') }
```

However this will print out the html tag, the output I'm getting look like this

```
当社の <a href="/home">ホーム</a> ページをご覧ください。
```

And finally the **.po** file looks like the following:

```
msgid ""
"Please visit our %{home_url} page"
msgstr "当社の %{home_url} ページをご覧ください。"

msgid ""
"home"
msgstr "ホーム"
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `.html_safe` at the end of the function call. Rails 4 escapes all HTML.

http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw

```
= 'Please visit out <a href="/">home</a> page'.html_safe
```

Comment: I forgot to follow up my own question since I got the answer. This is a correct answer. My solution was: = (_('Please visit our %{home_url} page') % {:home_url => link_to(_("home"), '/home') }).html_safe